# Using isDefined in a conditional statement- why not returning the form?

Tags: coldfusion

I am in the process of learning CF and have a question. Here is my code:

```
<cfif isDefined("form.fName")>

<cfoutput>Your data has been processed</cfoutput>

<cfelse>
<cfform name="myForm" action="exp2.cfm" id="myForm" format="html">

First name:<cfinput type="text" name="fName"><br/>
Last name:<cfinput type="text" name="lName"><br/>

<cfinput name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit data">

</cfform>
</cfif>
```

I'm wondering why if I click the submit button without
 entering anything into the text boxes, the message "Your data has been processed" appears. I did not define fName so shouldn't the form continue to display and not the message?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: (Edit) As mentioned in the other thread, `IsDefined()` is not the same as saying "is empty". FWIW, the rules for submission of the various form field types are defined in the [html specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). As long as a text box is given a "name", and it is not disabled, it will always be submitted. So from a CF perspective, the FORM variable representing the text box will always exist on the action page. Therefore, you must check the value's length instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of your input. `input type="text"` exists after the post in every case. It contains an empty string.
`input type="checkbox"` exists only if a checkbox was checked.

Comment: This. You'd have to check if your form field is blank rather than defined.